# Filter out unique value from object inside array using loadsh

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am trying to get the unique category from the following array using loadsh,

```
[{
  "listingId": "p106a904a-b8c6-4d2d-a364-0d21e3505010",
  "section": "section1",
  "category": "VIP PASS ",
  "type": "paper",
  "availableTickets": 1
}, {
  "listingId": "p106904a-b8c6-4d2d-a364-0d21e3505010",
  "section": "section1",
  "category": "VIP PASS ",
  "type": "paper",
  "availableTickets": 2
}, {
  "listingId": "pc8f54389-4e58-482a-9535-6917c2948764",
  "section": "1",
  "category": "WIP",
  "type": "paper",
  "availableTickets": 1
}]
```

This is what i have tried

```
 this.categories = _.uniq(this.listings, function (test: ListDAO) { return test.category; });
```

but the above returns the same array again. how can i get the output result as,

VIP PASS and WIP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without lodash and using `.reduce`:

```
let arr2 = arr.reduce((a, i) => a.indexOf(i.category) > -1 ? a : a.concat(i.category), []);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/42my6p08/

Comment: how to change this to support typescript

Comment: @faceturn that is valid js/typescript (as is mine)

Comment: is there a way to automatically remove empty string?

Comment: @faceturn - You can use `.filter` afterwards - `.filter(c => !!c)`

Comment: this.listings.reduce((a, i) => a.indexOf(i.category) > -1 ? a : a.concat(i.category), []).filter(c => !!c);

Comment: this returns empty string aswell

Comment: @faceturn - https://jsfiddle.net/42my6p08/1/ - empty strings filtered out

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `uniqBy` as `uniq` only accepts a regular array with no callback for each.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniqBy

You can try this:

```
this.categories = _.uniqBy(this.listings, ({ category }) => category);
```

---

If you want just the strings (as per comments) you can just do:

```
const getCategory = ({ category }) => category;

this.categories = _.uniqBy(this.listings, getCategory).map(getCategory);
```

(can also use the same callback function from your OP instead of mine.)

Comment: it does not work with typescript , there is an error on category

Comment: You can still use your same old callback `function (test: ListDAO) { return test.category; }` @faceturn

Comment: this.ticketCategories = _.uniqBy(this.listings, function (test: ListDAO) { return test.category; });

Comment: the above return correct unique objects , not string values as mentioned

Comment: again you can use your same callback... I was just making it smaller using es6 fanciness.

Comment: yeah using callback only, it returns unique objects not as strings

Comment: @faceturn ooo you want the strings? Then just do a `.map(function (test: ListDAO) { return test.category; })` after the uniqueBy call after if you really want to...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149416/discussion-between-face-turn-and-neal).

Comment: message: 'Binding element 'category' implicitly has an 'any' type.'

Comment: @faceturn ok. Let it have any type.

Comment: @faceturn - Then set a type for it, or set it to any, `category: any`

Comment: @tymeJV you cannot do that when destructuring... ts is confusing ;-P

Comment: @faceturn "errors" is not helpful when it comes to trying to help ;-)

Comment: const getCategory = ({ category: any }) => category; i cant put any here

Comment: For the eighth time just use the callback function from your question...

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `Map` and `reduce`.

```js
var arr = [{
  "listingId": "p106a904a-b8c6-4d2d-a364-0d21e3505010",
  "section": "section1",
  "category": "VIP PASS ",
  "type": "paper",
  "availableTickets": 1
}, {
  "listingId": "p106904a-b8c6-4d2d-a364-0d21e3505010",
  "section": "section1",
  "category": "VIP PASS ",
  "type": "paper",
  "availableTickets": 2
}, {
  "listingId": "pc8f54389-4e58-482a-9535-6917c2948764",
  "section": "1",
  "category": "WIP",
  "type": "paper",
  "availableTickets": 1
}];

var unique = arr.reduce((map, o) => (map.has(o.category) ? map : map.set(o.category)),new Map());
console.log(Array.from(unique.keys()));
```